# How to add specific menu on a specific page or pages

Tags: php, menus, user-registration, genesis-theme-framework, page-specific-settings

I'm looking for help on how to add specific menu on a specific page or pages with no plugin.

I know how to add and register a new menu like this:

```
//* Register third navigation menu position
function register_additional_menu() {
  register_nav_menu( 'third-menu' ,__( 'Third Navigation Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_additional_menu' );
add_action( 'genesis_before_content', 'add_third_nav_genesis' );

function add_third_nav_genesis() {
    echo'<div class="osastot-valikko">';
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'third-menu', 'container_class' => 'genesis-nav-menu js-superfish sf-js-enabled sf-arrows' ) );
    echo'</div>';
}
```

I would like to have a navigation menu named "Extra Menu" displayed only on three pages (post=6, post=7, post=8). What should I write in my function.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pages can have a specific template, so just create a new template and add the Menu on it.

You can copy the code on pages.php(this is the default page template) of you theme and paste on a new file (like "template-page-with-menu.php"). On the top of the code you must add the Template Name:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Page with Menu */ ?>
```

Then select this template on the pages that you want it.

[image]

Comment: Excellent suggestion. This way I could personalize those pages even more with specific sidebar contents etc.

Answer (score 2):

try working with a conditional statement:

```
function add_third_nav_genesis() {
    if( is_page( array( 6, 7, 8 ) ) ) {
        echo'<div class="osastot-valikko">';
        wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'third-menu', 'container_class' => 'genesis-nav-menu js-superfish sf-js-enabled sf-arrows' ) );
        echo'</div>';
    }
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

Comment: This is actually the answer what I was looking for but the Spadilha above suggested using page templates which didn't thought of. It gives me even more freedom to personalize the page. Thank you for help thou.